# large texture is black when imported

Tags: texturing, uv

I am trying to import a very large texture (about 2 gb) in .tif format. However, when i import the texture, the UV editor just shows a black rectangle.
I am prone to think that it's due to the size of the texture, because a similar but "smaller" (500 mb) texture works.
Is there a way to bypass this problem?

Comment: It may be because it's a tiff, are you sure this format works?

Comment: The manual says it does: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/media/image_formats.html

Comment: Yes, the 500 mb image is a .tiff too and blender opens it without problems.